# Getting 401 error from Old-Release Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, package-management

I am running Lubuntu 10.10 for a server that I use at home. I keep getting errors from the old-releases.ubuntu.com repositories I have to use. They are 401 access denied errors, has anyone else ever seen this before?

```
    W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.gz  401  Unauthorized    
W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz  401  Unauthorized    
W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.gz  401  Unauthorized   
W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-backports/main/source/Sources.gz  401  Unauthorized    
W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-backports/restricted/source/Sources.gz  401  Unauthorized    
W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-backports/universe/source/Sources.gz  401  Unauthorized   
W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-backports/multiverse/source/Sources.gz  401  Unauthorized    
W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  401  Unauthorized    
W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.gz  401  Unauthorized    
W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz  401  Unauthorized    
W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.gz  401  Unauthorized    
E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

These are the last few lines of the console output.

Comment: "Has any else ever seen this before?" Is that really your question?

Comment: Why can't you upgrade to a newer Ubuntu, such as 12.04 (which is LTS)?

Answer (score 1):

Lubuntu 10.10 is more than 2 years old now, and it is not a LTS. End of life, finished; upgrade (or downgrade to the LTS 10.4).